# "error: <method> cannot be overloaded" (but I am not trying to!)

Tags: c++, arduino

I cannot get past this error in my Arduino program. I do not understand. I am not trying to overload anything.

This is the *entire* program (what's left of it):

```
struct X {
    enum : byte {
        foo,
        bar
    };
    
    void update() {}
};

void setup() {}
void loop() {}
```

The error:

```
sketch_oct07a:8:7: error: 'void X::update()' cannot be overloaded
  void update() {}
       ^~~~~~
sketch_oct07a:8:6: error: with 'void X::update()'
  void update() {}
      ^~~~~~
exit status 1
'void X::update()' cannot be overloaded
```

**Edit:** I am not making this up!

[image]

Comment: The error message and the source you show are not related. If the compiler sees a second update function, it should be there or the compiler is broken. You may have some intermediate files somewhere or compiling from a different source directory?

Comment: @Klaus "The error message and the source you show are not related." Please look at the screenshot I have added.

Comment: Try one by one: change `X` name, change `update` name and see what happens.

Comment: @bolov No name changes have any effect.

Comment: What do you mean? You change the name and the error is with the old name?

Comment: @bolov No, I mean, it's not stopping the error: "error: 'void asdasd::updsdfdsfate()' cannot be overloaded"

Comment: It is a known Arduino IDE quirk. Move the function definition out of the class, leave only the declaration inside.

Comment: It's horrible. I come from the Java world. I can't cope with separate declaration and definition. It's an abomination.

Comment: The error goes away if I move the enum below the method. Horrible.

Comment: As the link to the duplicate shows, the bug is known since 2014 and still in the newest release of the IDE. Wow! Is really someone using this IDE? :-)

Comment: @Klaus I suppose so. It's how you program Arduinos.

Comment: Arduino IDE is buggy, and you don't have to use it, there are numerous tutorials that show how to do without.

Comment: At a first: There is no "arduinos". There are some series of micros e.g. ARM and AVR based, which you can also use with standard cross compilers installed without any IDE. If you like to use the arduino libraries, you can do this without any IDE at all. And the overall quality of the arduino libs is... :-)

Comment: You don't need the Arduino IDE at all. I use VS Code with PlatformIO and I have access to all the goodies of a modern IDE and I can even compile with C++17.

Comment: I reproduced it. It is still a bug of the Arduino builder. As workaround use `class X` instead of `struct X`

Comment: @Juraj Wow. Horrible. Thank you.

Comment: the duplicate question has it as answer

Comment: @Klaus & bolov That's... interesting to know, but unfortunately that colossally exceeds my patience for the C++ declaration-definition split, and also for makefiles. I would rather suffer thru the quirks of the old Arduino compiler because at least it TRIES to fix the defects where C++ can't see functions further down in the source file (which I infer is what has caused this error), and while I would dearly like to be able to set a few compiler flags to enable modern language features, at least the Arduino IDE frees me from ever having to touch a makefile again.